# Overflow-y visible but overflow-x on parent hidden

Tags: html, css, overflow

This has probably been asked a million times, and I have gone through some threads but still not able to implement it as needed.

I would like to show absolute positioned info boxes on hover inside a carousel,
the only way I am able to make this work is whenever one of the parent has overflow turned off,
but this would also mean that the x-axis overflow will become visible --> not desired effect.

I have the following html markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrap-outer">
        <div class="wrap">

        <div class="box">
            <div class="box--title">Title</div>
            <div class="box--hidden">
                <div class="box--hidden-inner">
                    Hidden Text, show on hover
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ...

    </div>

</div>
```

and with css played around with some options and this is the last (not working):

```
.wrap-outer {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrap {
    width: 1800px;
    overflow-y: visible; /* not working! */
}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 7px;
}

.box--hidden {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; /* when removed, still not working */
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    max-height: 0;
}

.box:hover .box--hidden {
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

Again, I did check some posts on SO, but couldn't reproduce it for the specific carousel created with Slick slider, so don't shoot me.

([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hzt7c8yb/))
([fiddle with slick slider](https://jsfiddle.net/nm9qorwy/1/))

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, two ideas: 1) this only works with a height limit to the tooltips: give the slider padding-bottom as placeholder space for the tooltip and negative margin-bottom: https://jsfiddle.net/6rd1psg8/2/ 2) arrange the tooltip outside of the slider via js.

Comment: @TiHausmann, I had tried this hack, but it comes with some issues, main issue being that the pointer events under the slider are now drag events for the slider :(

Comment: Yes it's hacky. To fix the pointer issues you could only apply the padding on hover though https://jsfiddle.net/xj70r18q/